# Updating Rcpp::NumericMatrix in Fortran

Tags: r, fortran, rcpp

I am working on interfacing some existing Fortran code for some R analyses.  As a precursor I wanted to create a test function to confirm how I pass matrices in and out of the functions.

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26194225/rcpp-returning-c-array-as-numericmatrix-to-r) I thought I could use `Rcpp` to pass a `NumericMatrix` pointer to the C function with the `.begin()` method.

fortran_test.f

```
   subroutine test(matrix, M, N)

   IMPLICIT NONE

   integer, intent(in)  ::  M,N
   double precision, intent(inout)   ::  matrix(M,N)
   integer   ::  i,j

   do 10 i=1,M
     do 20 j=1,N
         matrix(i,j) = 2.0D0
 20   end do
 10 end do

    end
```

cpp_test.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

extern "C"
{
    void test_(double *, int, int);
}

using namespace Rcpp;

//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP cpp_test(NumericMatrix X){

    int nr = X.nrow();
    int nc = X.ncol();

    test_(X.begin(), nr, nc);

    Rcpp::Rcout << X << std::endl;

    return X;
}
```

However, when I try:

```
mydata <- matrix(rnorm(16), 4, 4)
cpp_test(mydata)
```

The program just crashes.

Strangely, if I try to use the `.Fortran` interface (which I am trying to avoid as I would like to do some further C++ before the Fortran call) the function doesn't crash but the matrix doesn't update either.  I through in some `Print` statements in the Fortran to confirm that the internal `matrix` object is updating but it isn't returning those changes.

What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I have since noticed the the `.Fortran` call does return a list with the updated matrix.  I would prefer however to have the 'in-place' modification but I don't now if that is possible.  The C++ interface initially described above is my true goal.

Comment: As you're doing R->C++->Fortran, you may want to consider using Fortan's C interoperability (see [tag:fortran_iso_c_binding]).  In particular, possibly the `value` attribute for those scalar integer arguments in the Fortran subroutine.

Comment: @francescalus yes, that appears to have solved the problem.  If I use the iso_c_binding and add the 'value' attribute for the scalar int arguments it seems to work now.  Thank you.

Comment: Just using `iso_c_binding` should not solve it, `bind(C)` is necessary too (it changes the internal meaning of `value`).